# DB representation of Product "Specials" where specials varies by fields

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

I am trying to work out the best way to represent the concept of "Specials" in my database - these relate to "products for sale". Each special will offer some sort of discount however they will vary in the sense that one will just be a simple price reduction but others will be things like "Buy x Get y Half Price" or "30% off category x". I don't anticipate having more than around 10 specials types... but requirements change and I need to make sure I can handle more if the need arises.

I am trying to come up with a simple way to represent these in my DB however the way I see it I am either going to have to create a table per special or I am going to have to have a specials table with loads of columns of which 90% of the values will be NULL. I intend to have a SpecialType table which will group all specials together by type e.g. "Discount","Buy x get y Free" and this will be used to determine the business logic in the respective app layer. Additionally I was thinking I could go down the path of having 1 table per special type and then caching the results (essentially caching the renderable output per product) that could be updated on a regular basis, say every 5 minutes, the intention of this would be to perform a large number of joins (EDIT - these would actually probably be UNIONS) but do it fairly infrequently as the data is not real-time critical in the sense that a 5 minute delay wouldn't kill anyone.

I would appreciate any feedback on how to handle this situation in the tidiest manner whilst keeping my database normalized.

Comment: Are you just displaying the applicable specials, or do you calculate the price and similar business logic (will there be code changes required if a new special type pops up)?

Comment: Yeah I anticipate that the calculations will be made in the BLL based on the special type. Therefore additional logic will have to be added as new types are added. Unless of course there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an addition of a Special type will require a code change, and you cannot reasonably anticipate all possible special types, I would be comfortable to create a separate table for each type of special, along with some kind of master table, that would contain the special types, names, descriptions, etc...

Using a single table with lots of inapplicable fields will tend to become an [Inner Platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect) and that is almost always an overkill.

BTW, one of the most unpleasant surprises in my life, was when I found out about a new promotion that required code/database changes from a TV commercial.